# What does this operation do?

Tags: python

`checks = len(g[max(g, key=lambda key: len(g[key]))])`

g is a dictionary of lists. What does the operation above return?

Comment: This gets the length of the longest list in the dictionary in a very convoluted way.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: This looks like a convoluted way of writing `max(map(len, g.values()))`. It is hard to tell without a reliable example of g, though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "What does this code do?" is generally [too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797) of a question here; if *trying the code and seeing what happens* doesn't answer the question, then it is hard to answer because *we do not know what you don't understand about it, or why*. Separately: this code presumably came from somewhere. If you wrote it yourself, then the responsibility for understanding it is on you. Otherwise, the appropriate person to ask is *the author* - whether by direct contact, or reading comments or documentation.